# CSS Flex Box: varying the number of items on each row

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

As an exercise, I am working on using Flex Box to implement the following layout:

```
┌───────────────────────────────┐
│ header                        │
└───────────────────────────────┘
┌─────┐ ┌───────────────────────┐
│ nav │ │ main                  │
│     │ │                       │
└─────┘ └───────────────────────┘
┌───────────────────────────────┐
│ footer                        │
└───────────────────────────────┘
```

My initial thought was to use:

```
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

but I’m not sure what to do about the rest. Currently I use:

```
header,footer {
    width: 100%;
}
nav {
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
main {
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 4;
}
```

with a bit of extra fine tuning.

This works, but it seems contrived.

An alternative solution would be to wrap the `nav` and `main` element inside a `div`, but I am trying to avoid that as it reduces flexibility.

The question is, what is the most appropriate way to have a layout with one element on some rows, and multiple elements on others?

Answer (score 2):

The point is in `flex-basis` which needs to be defined, i.e. different from the *initial value* of `auto`, in order to enable wrapping of additional elements, if the prefered way is doing it without the additional *parent element*, which is perfectly fine:

```js
$('button:first-of-type').click(function(){
  $('<div>3</div>').insertAfter('.insertAfter');
});

$('button:last-of-type').click(function(){
  $('div:not(.first)').toggleClass('flexBasis');
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

body > * {text-align: center}

header, footer {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  background: #f88;
}

nav {
  flex-basis: 20%;
  background: lightgreen;
}

main {
  flex-basis: 80%;
  background: lightblue;
}

.first {
  flex-basis: 33.33%;
  background: lightgray;
}

div {
  flex: 1; /* not enough */
  background: gray;
}

.flexBasis {
  flex: 1 25%; /* enough */
}

.insertAfter ~ div {color: #fff; background: #000}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Add</button>
<button>Toggle flex-basis</button>

<header>Header</header>
<nav>Nav</nav>
<main>Main</main>
<div class="first">1</div>
<div class="first">1</div>
<div class="first">1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>2</div>
<div class="insertAfter">2</div>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two thing you should add:

1) Make the body `display:flex` to turn it into a flex container

2) Use the `flex` shorthand to indicate the flex grow and basis to the header and footer. By making the basis 100vw, you make does flex items 100% of the viewport width

```
flex: 1 100vw;
```

Hope this helps :)

```css
body {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background: red;
    margin:0;
}

header,footer {
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
    flex: 1 100vw;
}
nav {
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
     background: green;
}
main {
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 4;
     background: pink;
}
```

```html
<body>
<header>&nbsp</header>
<nav>&nbsp</nav>
<main>&nbsp</main>
<footer>&nbsp</footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Sorry, I have already added the `display: flex` property. I hadn’t mentioned it in my code as it was not part of the question. I’ll add it to the question, though. As regards the width, I plan to use a different width. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: The width i mention are only for the header and footer. Is there something in my answer that wasn't as you asked. I asked this so i can fix it